# Insert 1 row from 1 table and 2nd row form other table into a new table and so on

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-insert

I have a table TABLE101 with the following fields:

```
COL1    COLB   COLC   COLD
ACT1    UYT    876     KJH
ACT2    CFG    976     TRY
```

I have another table TABLE102 as under:

```
COL1      COL2    COL3     COL4      COL5     COL6    
ACt1      A1_B1    98       UI                  2
ACT2      C1                00         N
ACT2      D1_D4     1       PP         Y       RT       
ACT2      A1_F1    9T       UI                 2
```

Now i want to insert data into a 3rd table which has all the fields from table101 and table 102 like:

```
COL1   COLB   COLC   COLD  COL2   COL3    COL4     COL5      COL6        LVL
ACT1   UYT    876    KJH                                                  1
ACt1                       A1_B1    98      UI                  2         2
ACT2   CFG    976    TRY                                                  1
ACT2                       C1               00       N
ACT2                       D1_D4     1      PP       Y         RT         2
ACT2                       A1_F1    9T      UI                  2         2
```

So 1st i need to insert 1st row from table101 and for corresponding COL1 value i need to insert row from TABLE102. 
In table101, COL1 is unique but in table 101 col1 can have multiple rows. 
If i insert row from table101, i have to set lvl col to 1 and if i insert form table102 i set lvl col to 2

How can i do so?

Comment: Why in 3rd table there  is not second row from TABLE102 table ?

Comment: @oto - Why 3rd table? all 3 table structures are different. 3rd table is combination of table 1 and table 2

Comment: in TABLE102  table, you have row where `COL2 = 'C1'`. where is this row in your combined table ?

Comment: Edited to have that row, missed it.

Comment: Is AC**t**1 (with lower-case t) a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` for combining your tables. Then use `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax for inserting into 3rd table.

```
SELECT COL1    , COLB,  COLC ,  COLD,             NULL AS COL2,  NULL AS COL3,  NULL AS  COL4, NULL AS    COL5,  NULL AS    COL6,        1 AS LVL FROM TABLE101 
UNION ALL
SELECT COL1,   NULL AS COLB,  NULL AS COLC, NULL AS COLD, COL2,  COL3,    COL4  ,   COL5  ,    COL6   ,  2 AS   LVL FROM TABLE102
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
create table table101 as
  select 'ACT1' col1, 'UYT' colb, 876 colc, 'KJH' cold from dual union all
  select 'ACT2'     , 'CFG'     , 976     , 'TRY'      from dual
;
commit;
select * from table101;

COL1 COLB COLC COLD
---- ---- ---- ----
ACT1 UYT   876 KJH
ACT2 CFG   976 TRY

2 rows selected.

create table table102 as
  select 'ACT1' col1, 'A1_B1' col2, '98' col3, 'UI' col4, null col5, '2' col6 from dual union all
  select 'ACT2'     , 'C1'        , null     , '00'     , 'N'      , null     from dual union all
  select 'ACT2'     , 'D1_D4'     , '1'      , 'PP'     , 'Y'      , 'RT'     from dual union all
  select 'ACT2'     , 'A1_F1'     , '9T'     , 'UI'     , null     , '2'      from dual
;
commit;
select * from table102;

COL1 COL2  COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6
---- ----- ---- ---- ---- ----
ACT1 A1_B1 98   UI        2
ACT2 C1         00   N
ACT2 D1_D4 1    PP   Y    RT
ACT2 A1_F1 9T   UI        2

4 rows selected.

create table table110 (col1 varchar2(4000), colb varchar2(4000), colc number, cold varchar2(4000),
  col2 varchar2(4000), col3 varchar2(4000), col4 varchar2(4000), col5 varchar2(4000), 
  col6 varchar2(4000), lvl number);

Table TABLE110 created.
```

Insert statement and outcome:

```
insert into table110
select col1, colb, colc, cold, null, null, null, null, null, 1
  from table101
union all
select col1, null, null, null, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, 2
  from table102
;
commit;
select * from table110;

COL1 COLB COLC COLD COL2  COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6 LVL
---- ---- ---- ---- ----- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---
ACT1 UYT   876 KJH                              1
ACT2 CFG   976 TRY                              1
ACT1                A1_B1 98   UI        2      2
ACT2                C1         00   N           2
ACT2                D1_D4 1    PP   Y    RT     2
ACT2                A1_F1 9T   UI        2      2

6 rows selected.

select * from table110;
```